# Is it possible to create a blurring page dimmer with Semantic UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a blurring page dimmer in Semantic UI.

[**The official docs**](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dimmer.html) state examples for both page dimmers as well as blurring segment dimmers. But is there a way to combine the two?

It seems from the examples [**there**](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dimmer.html#blurring) that the container to be dimmed needs to be decorated with the `blurring` class. Then, the `dimmer()` method is called with either `'show'` or `'hide'` to control the appearance of the dimmer.

**But what if I want to dim the entire page?** Do I add the `blurring` class to the `body` tag? Or is there a special way to achieve the same? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can add the `blurring` class to the `<body>` tag to achieve the desired effect.